# Read and Update plist in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I would like to let users choose to store username or not at the login page, so my plist has 2 keys: **userIsSaved(bool)**, and **username(string)**

Here's my script:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"userinfo" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *plistDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
BOOL userIsSaved = [[plistDic objectForKey:@"userIsSaved"] boolValue];
NSString *username = plistDic[@"username"];

if (lg.saveUserSwitch.isOn){

    if (userIsSaved == false){

        [plistDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"userIsSaved"];
        plistDic[@"username"] = lg.usernameFld.text;

        [plistDic writeToFile: path atomically: YES];

        if ([plistDic writeToFile: path atomically: YES] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"!!!Save plist file failed");
        }

    }

}
```

I got some questions:

1. Why can't I write `plistDic[@"userIsSaved"] = true` to update the bool value? how to properly update it? `[plistDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"userIsSaved"]` seems to change the type of it. How should I read it?
2. I can't write the plistDic to the plist. I don't know what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer

1. You can't store a boolean (or integer or float or ...) into a dictionary - only an object can be stored. So you need to convert it to an object first, in this case, `NSNumber` as you did. You can also shortcut it with
   `plistDic setObject:@(YES) forKey:@"userIsSaved"]`
2. To write first get the path to the correct directory, which typically is something like

```
    NSURL * dir = [[NSFileManager.defaultManager URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].firstObject
               URLByAppendingPathComponent:NSBundle.mainBundle.bundleIdentifier
               isDirectory:YES];
```

Then you can write using something like
`NSString * myFile = [dir.path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mylist.plist"];`

and then write to `myFile` in stead.

Note also maybe a good idea to use URLs.

Comment: my path includes ```userinfo.plist``` already. What's the use of appending mylist.plist to it?

Comment: Ooops you are right - I thought you are getting *documents* path there, which is what you should do. You should get documents path and then append a file to it as I show and then write to that in stead.

Comment: Is your way creating a new file? I just want to override the existing one

Comment: That is the problem - you can not update files in your bundle.

Comment: I must apologise - I did not realise you are reading the file from your own bundle. That snippet I post is standard way of getting path to where you can write so when I saw bundle I just skipped it and assumed you are getting the dir. You must check, I show you a complete example where you can create local files but there are other locations as well e.g. the documents. The one I show is the Application Support which is what you need I think but just consider a bit what you are storing then decide where. Documents don't sound right here.

Comment: I think I should store data in UserDefaults instead. Thanks though!

Comment: Pleasure - If a plist I'd go for a file, but if you have just one BOOL in there maybe user defaults is much easier.